# who is call to security config in spring security?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new with spring security.
I have security Config class

How is calling to this class ?

does the controller call it ?

how does the controller can get my parameters from my from ? ( in my case emailInput and passwrodInput )

```
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.*;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
 @EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .usernameParameter("emailInput")
            .passwordParameter("passwordInput")
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
/*   
    http
      .formLogin()
        .usernameParameter("emailInput")
        .passwordParameter("passwordInput");
        */
  }

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    return encoder;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.M2/reference/htmlsingle/
section 3.2 and section 3.3.

You have an example there.

Your controllers do not call security subsystem directly. You should:

1) configure Spring to render your login form by using .loginPage("/login") and assign your MVC controller to this path ("/login"). This controller should render empty login form

2) in this login form create input fields login and password which by standard have names j_username and j_password, but your overrode them with names emailInput, passwordInput

3) set <form action="/j_spring_security_check" method="POST">

EDIT:

I would like to give you example from my projects, but I prefer XML (not Java) configuration objects. So here it goes:

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Map<String,Object> model = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        if (request.getParameter("error") != null) {
            model.put("error", true);
        }
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("login",model);
        return mv;
    }
}
```

login.jsp:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

    <form action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method="post">
                <c:if test="${param.error != null}">        
                        Invalid username and password.
                </c:if>
                    <input id="username" name="emailInput" type="text" />
                    <input id="password" name="passwordInput" type="password"/>
                    <input type="hidden"                        
    name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
    value="${_csrf.token}"/>
                    <input type="submit">Sign in</input>
    </form>
```

and your configuration in Java should be something like:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
 http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .usernameParameter("emailInput")
        .passwordParameter("passwordInput")
        .loginPage("/login") 
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .httpBasic();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: 1. where do I need to configure the loginpage and the mvc in the secuirty-web.xml ?                                                  2 and 3 . can I create html file and not jsp file ?  and How the securtiyConfig will be called ?

Comment: could we have s short chat ?

Comment: in the example I didn't see that the have filds j_username  and j_password and they didn't send the action. Maybe could you create short example ?

Comment: why do I need to see the action form ? do I need to create form ? can I do it without form ?

Comment: I edited my answer and gave you an example. I hope that my explanation is much clearer now.

Comment: does in your example the .usernameParameter should be username and .passwordparameter should be password ?

Comment: maybe could we have short chat ?

Comment: Sorry, I am busy today and cannot chat. I made a small mistake in parameters names in login.jsp and corrected it.

Comment: thanks for all the support last issue what will the configure wil do after all the code does it will call to the servlet login ? what is the flow ? and again thanks for all the support

Comment: Hi. This is a very basic question related to architecture of Spring Security that is addressed in the link above. In general you configure your code using your config class which should set which URL-s are restricted and when user login is required. When user tries to access such URL he or she is redirected by Spring to your Controller which presents your login.jsp and renders your form. In next step authentication is performed by Spring itself (j_spring_security_check) and if successful - user is taken back to the original address, if not - he is taken back to /login?error=1